# How to avoid 127.0.0.1 on myIpAddress() in .pac files

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-11.04, pac

Any idea how to avoid myIpAddress() always returning 127.0.0.1, instead of actual the host IP address?

Environment is Ubuntu 11.04 with Firefox 4.0.1.

The standard answer on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config#myIpAddress) of removing entries from the /etc/hosts file didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has finally worked, was to update the entry in /etc/hosts correctly with the IP address.

In Ubuntu, executable files in the `/etc/network/if-up.d` directory are being executed after the network manager configures a network interface.

This script does update the ip address accordingly:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ "$IFACE" = lo ]; then
    exit 0
fi

myHostName=T410

# Remove current line with hostname at the end of line
sed -i '/'$myHostName'$/ d' /etc/hosts

# Add new entry to hosts file
ipaddr=$(ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
echo "$ipaddr $myHostName" >>/etc/hosts
```